# How to assign value to public class properties?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a  e.g. `Customer.php` and `Address.php` class, I want to assign value from an array to public properties defined on the class.

In my `Customer.php` has following properties:

```
public string id;
public string name;
public Address $address;
```

I am using loop to assign value to the properties listed

```
protected function useState(array $state): void
{
    foreach ($state as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

But there's an problem when trying to assign to `Address` because it's not an instance of `Address`, array used.

Is there any idea i can assign the value to the `Address`?

Comment: And reason you're not using a relationship? Pseudo-code example: `public function address() { return $this->{relationshipMethod}(Address::class, ...); }`?

Comment: Because not to rely on eloquent relationship

Comment: Right, but you can still define the relationship, remove `public Address $address`, then `$this->key = $value` should work (`$key` being `address`, `value` being an instance of `Address`). Laravel uses magic methods to translate relationship functions to properties, so `$model->address` is available.

Comment: Address class just same as Customer class, just consists of public properties and other related entity. I just want to know is there a solution to assign my value into Address Entity when detect the array key address.

Comment: Can you do a `dd($state)` in your `useState` method, or in the loop, `if ($key == 'address'){ dd($value); }`; that should help debug why it thinks `$value` is an array and not an instance of `Address`.

Comment: It is an array, i want to assign the address value into the `Address` entity when it is an instance of  entity classes. It something like `$address = new Address(); $address->line1 = "Road 8....";` by using loop the public properties from `Address` and assign the array value based on key given.

Comment: Is there a possible to detect if the public properties is instances of classes and i will create new instance for the class?

Comment: Ah, I see. Dynamically handling that might be difficult. You could do an `if` or `switch` to handle `address` (and any other known models), then do `$this->$key = new Address($value)`, but that requires pre-definition of the keys and Models you'd convert.